# Is there a way to replace the end of a string, starting at a given substring

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the string `banana | 10` and want to replace everything from `|`  to the end of the string with `9`. The output I want would be `banana | 9`. How could I achieve this? I've looked into `.replace()`, `.split()` and converting the string into a list of characters, and looping over them until I find the bit that should be replaced, but just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use `re` module(regex module):

```py
import re
myString = "banana | 10"
re.sub(r"\|.+", r"| 9", myString)
```

##### Output

```
banana | 9
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourStr = 'banana | 10'
yourStr = yourStr[:yourStr.index('|') + 2] + '9'
print(yourStr)
```

> banana | 9

The other `regex` solutions are more elegant, but this is more readable. You can decide what better suits you.

Comment: This will break whenever the number is not 2 digits long

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can work.
Code:

```py
string = 'banana | 10 ';
pos = string.find('|')
left_string = string[:pos+2];
final_string = left_string + '9'
print(final_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use split() method...
This would be helpful for you to understand the method.

```
sep = ' | '
new_value = 9
s ='banana | 10'.split(sep=sep)
print( s[0] + sep + str(new_value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture `|` followed by optional spaces without a newline in group 1, and match the rest of the line that is to be removed.

In the replacement use capture group 1 followed by `9`

```
import re

s = "banana | 10"
pattern = r"(\|[^\S\n]*).*"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\g<1>9", s))
```

Output

```
banana | 9
```

If you want to match digits and at least 1 or more spaces, then use:

```
(\|[^\S\n]+)\d+
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZWY7sd/1)

Answer (score 1):

The logic can probably be improved but something like this might work:

```
text = "banana | 10"

if "|" in text:
   tmp = text.split("|")
   print (tmp[0] + "| 9")
```